# MySQL insert throws column specified twice due to case insensivity

Tags: mysql, insert

to my knowledge MySQL should be able to handle case sensitive column names on unix systems. While it is possible to create two columns which names only differ in case sensitivity (I hope this is the correct term), INSERT seems to have a problem with that.

Let me give an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
ALTER TABLE test ADD `u` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE test ADD `U` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Everything's fine! MySQL creates a table and adds two columns. The first one is named `u` and the second one is named `U`.
So, presumably MySQL is able to deal with case sensitive column names.

But the a simple insert command like this one

```
INSER INTO test (`U`,`u`) VALUES (1,1);
```

throws an error message saying

```
ERROR 1110 (42000): Column 'U' specified twice
```

This looks kind of inconstant to me: First accepting these columns names and then refusing to insert.
Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

By the way, the MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: Can not reproduce. Fails at adding the second column already...Why in the world would you want to have that anyway?

Comment: hm, interesting. Thanks for your support and input anyway! :) I decided to handle this issue in the parser script. Btw, no one _wants_ to have that instead of a descent database design but in some analyses not all item are known at first sight and so columns have to be created on-the-go while parsing. Don't worry: No productive system. ;)

Comment: Having items as columns sounds like bad database design, too. No offense...

Comment: It truly is! I don't like it either. But it seemed the "easiest" (yet not best) way. How would you do it? If you had a vector `X = {"x":1.0, "y":1.0", "z":1.0}` and another vector `Y = {"x":2.0, "y":2.0", "z":2.0}` it is easy to store them in a database. But if you then get a third one `Z = {"x":1.0, "a":3.0", "b":3.0}` and all vectory need to have all items (setting 0 if no value exists), how would you do it to have `X = {"a":0.0, "b":0.0, "x":1.0, "y":1.0", "z":1.0}` and `Y = {"a":0.0, "b":0.0, "x":2.0, "y":2.0", "z":2.0}` and `Z = {"a":3.0, "b":3.0, "x":1.0, "y":0.0", "z":0.0}` ?

Comment: Additionally: When `X` and `Y` are processed, you do not know that there will be a vector with `a` and `b` as items. So it is not possible to go through all data, get all item names, create the columns and then process all vectors. Setting up a "growing" database seemed okay for this purpose, although it is bad design. :/